# Magento 2.3 fresh installation issue : tinymce.js not load

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Loading failed for the  with source “/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/tinymce.js”.

[image]

Comment: Have deleted the pub/static and redeployed ?

Comment: Yes. But not works that.

Comment: Facing the same issue here on cms page edit.

Comment: I figured out that the tinymce was overwritten in one of my custom module. I disabled those modules and it works fine now. Hope this helps.

Comment: This comes in the admin side. How you was got that module?

Comment: @PratikKamani have you find any solution for this, i am also facing the same issue  could you please advise?

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary your suggestion is working for me thanks which is very helpful

Comment: @PratikKamani did you solved ?

Answer (score 7):

search for text 'tinymce' in your web magento directory

2.3 not use tinymce anymore so somewhere in your web still use tinymce so you get this problem because magento can't find define tinymce

I think new version using 'tinymce4' or 'tinymceDeprecated'

the right way in magento 2.3.1 for use tinymce

```
define(['wysiwygAdapter'], function(wysiwyg){
   // Your code here
});
```

Comment: i have been facing the same issue in M2.3.1 upgraded from m2.2.3  CE could u please advise?

Comment: you can search in all your custom modules have use require 'tinymce'. This cause your problem. Because every module before 2.3 still use this require and when you update to 2.3.1 magento can't find this package anymore

Answer (score 0):

**If you're working on Magento 2.3.* Try this:**

```
composer require pavelleonidov/module-tinymce4
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```